# Using class properties in angular templates

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use a property from a template in angular. It doesn't work and I can't figure out why. I've set up an example here:

https://github.com/Fulkerson/angular-property

It is the example from the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6). My [commit](https://github.com/Fulkerson/angular-property/commit/c3880dac1a23717d39daa787606925d12ef0185b) adds the property `propname` which simply returns `name` and uses it in the dashboard (main page).

Basically what I want to do is add multiple properties that process a field in different ways. But why is it I cannot use the properties from templates, and how can accomplish what I want to do in another way?

Comment: Could you paste the relevant code here to make it easier for us to review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data returned by the `heroService.getHeroes` method is plain JSON object (without the getter you defined in the Hero class). If you want to use the getter defined in the class you have to return an Array of real `Hero` instance.

1/ We add a constructor for the Hero class in app/hero.ts for convenience

```
  constructor ({id,name} = {id: undefined, name: undefined}) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
```

2/ Instead of returning plain js data from heroService we map to obtain an array of Hero instance in dashboard.component.ts

```
getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => 
        this.heroes = heroes
        .slice(1, 5)
        .map(hero => new Hero(hero))
      );
  }
```

And Tadaa !

[Here is the stackblitz created upon your github repo](https://stackblitz.com/github/yqnimklb)

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly fine now. The fact that the returned data by `getHeroes` is just plain JSON and not converted into the type specified really explains many of the issues I had throughout the tutorial. The tutorial is not very clear on that.

The stackblitz link does not seem to work by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your problem is that, though you're adding a new getter to the `Hero` class, in the dashboard you're listing the heroes coming from the service. The problem is that the service is mocking data, and that data is, in truth, a simple array of objects (defined in `in-memory-data.service.ts`):

```
const heroes = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
```

In the original example this does not matter as the `Hero` class is used there basically as an interface or type annotation. You, however, are giving that class methods, but those methods do not exist in the array.

So, basically, your template is trying to access a `propname` property from the items of this array. That property, as you see, is `undefined`. As a result, you don't see the name in the page. To avoid this, just change the definition of the array:

```
const heroes = [
      Object.assign(new Hero(), { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' }),
      ...
    ];
```

(you can also give `Hero` a constructor with parameters and use it instead of `Object.assign`). This way you'll get an array of true `Hero` objects.

Comment: Thank you!  I did not realize I was working on plain JSON towards the end of the tutorial.

Comment: Mr. Nice is one of my heroes too

Comment: @Fulkerson, could you mark it as an answer, please?